# Error 422 on POST request Angular 2 Drupal 8

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, drupal

I'm trying to send a POST request to a Drupal website (create a new node of content type test), but I get error 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

This is my service in Angular:

```
createBlog(blog: Blog): Observable<any>{
  let url = this.API_URL + "entity/node";
   blog._links = {type : { href: 'http://example.co.uk/rest/type/node/test' } };
  return this.http.post(url, blog,  {headers:this.headers}).map(res => res.json()).catch(err => {
 console.log(blog)
    return Observable.throw(err.json);
  });
}
```

And this is what I get in console after form submission:

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.stringify(data)` method before posting via http.

```
return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(blog), headers).map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

**EDIT:**

Aso use header like below.

```
import { Headers, Response, RequestOptions} from "@angular/http"; 
...

let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
let body = JSON.stringify(blog);
return this.http.post(url, body, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.Is quite strange as is working well on Postman.

Comment: i forgot to add RequestOptions, send options insted of headers. check edit may be this will fix the issue.

Comment: I've noticed that but still no luck...I have the headers set up somewhere else in the servise file as I use them for multiple GET requests... and i need 'Content-Type': 'application/hal+json'

Comment: Please go through this tutorial this will help https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables

Answer (score 0):

For this function:

```
addTask (task: Task): Observable<Task> {

  const url = `${this.mainUrl}/entity/node`;  

  const postReturn = this.http.post(url, task, httpHaljson);

  return postReturn
}
```

This is how i declare the api and the header:

```
  mainUrl : 'http://drupal.dd:8083',
  httpHaljson : {
                  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 
                  "X-CSRF-Token": "Qfnczb1SUnvOAsEy0A_xuGp_rkompgO2oTkCBOSEItM",
                  "Authorization": "Basic Qfnczb1SUnvOAsEy0A_xuGp_rkompgO2oTkCBOSEItM", // encoded user/pass - this is admin/123qwe
                  // "Content-Type": "application/json"
                  "Content-Type": "application/hal+json"
                  })
                }
```

and the Task, the most important one, have to do something like this:

```
{
  "_links": {
    "type": {
      "href": "http://drupal.dd:8083/rest/type/node/task"
    }
  },
  "title": {
    "value": "I am a new task"
  },
  "type": {
    "target_id": "task"
  }
}
```

For that, after recive some data from the form I do this:

```
   onSubmit(name: string, body:string): void {
   let task: any = {
       _links: null,
       type: null,
       title: null,
       body: null     
    };

    task._links = {type: {"href": "http://drupal.dd:8083/rest/type/node/task"} };
    task.type = {target_id: "task"};
    task.title = {value: name};
    task.body = { "": body};

      this.taskService.addTask(task)
        .subscribe(task => {
          this.tasks.push(task);
          // console.log(JSON.stringify(task));

          this.getTasks();
        });
    }
```

Look that my: console.log(JSON.stringify(task)); is the key, with this one, you can see how far are you from create what drupal want.

Look this [guide](https://josuevalrob.com/angular-drupal8):